# Best way to populate model when form validation fails?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a detail page which displays product information, at the bottom of this page is a form to post a comment.

The detail page has a request mapping /view :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String view(@ModelAttribute("cf") CommentForm cf, Model model) {
```

This is where i put data in my model ( model.addAttribute ) that can be used by my view.

No problem here.

When the user submits a new comment using the form, and forgets to type in a comment, a problem arises.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/comment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String comment(@ModelAttribute("cf") @Valid CommentForm cf, BindingResult result, Model model,
RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {    
if (result.hasErrors()) {
return "apps.view";
}
```

As you can see if there is a error, it returns the view template. But this goes wrong, because no data has been put in the model.

What is the best way to get the data in the model when form validation fails?

My first guess would be to create a function putDataInModel() and call it from view() and when form validation fails (before return "view").

Although I'm open and hoping for better and maybe cleaner solutions.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you wan't to show error messages in view? Then use Spring Error Tag. Do you wan't to log missing values? Then enable logging for the right (Spring) class.

Comment: Both the actual values as well as the error messages are part of the model so those are there. You can use the form tags to show the values/errors as you like. If they aren't there you are doing something in your code to destroy a proper (normal) working of the controllers.

Comment: I'm not sure how i can make it more clear, but to be more clearer my ModelAttribute CommentForm does not contain product information (hence the name). So if form submission fails the data from the form is available but not my product information. I give a solution to solve this (second last sentence), but "i'm open and hoping for better and maybe cleaner solutions".

Answer (score 0):

One option is to keep your CommentForm in the session

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
@SessionAttributes("cf")
public class ProductController {
```

Another option is to use the @ModelAttribute to populate the model on every request

```
public class ProductController {

   @ModelAttribute("product")
   public Product populateProduct() {
       return /*data from service or DAO */
   }

   ...
}
```